# Which World Champions other than Viswanathan Anand had a jolly personality?

Tags: world-championship, anand, karjakin

First of all, congratulations to Viswanathan Anand for winning the Candidates 2014 tournament and qualifying for a rematch with Magnus Carlsen later this year!

I saw this interesting gesture made by Anand towards Karjakin after their game in the Candidates 2014 tournament (video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab2trGXekwc&list=PLuSxF13JFumcREcww69-6ChtNjLepmQ79) at 5:42:54). Anand just needed a draw to win the tournament and qualify for the World Championship, but Karjakin dragged the game for a whole 90 moves, making Anand patiently work and wait for the result. After Karjakin finally accepted the draw, Anand made a joking gesture as though he was going to attack Karjakin.

[image]

It seems to me that chess players can be often thought of as "**too serious**", but World Champions like Anand have helped change the outlook on that.

Which other World Champions in chess history had a jolly personality like Anand? Or is Anand unique in that regard?

Comment: "Jolly personality" seems very subjective to me. Is there a right answer to this question? Is there even a wrong answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah. I somehow missed that during live relay. Thanks for sharing.

Mikhail Tal comes to mind based on his [Life and Games](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13674.Life_Games_of_Mikhail_Tal). He mentioned about 'forgetting' to stop his clock during tournament games for the sake of his time troubled opponents.

I don't know how many of us mere mortals could consider doing that. He must have been a jolly good fellow.

Answer (score 5):

OK, the only World Champion I can name for being jolly besides already mentioned Mikhail Tal is probably Vladimir Kramnik, who is always a pleasure to listen to in interviews, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCURWc4tlYQ

If your counting the FIDE world champions then Ruslan Ponomariov springs to mind, 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSirU4aJbKU

NOT world champions, but some top Grandmaster's who are very jolly

Levon Aronian is known for being an exceptionally nice fellow, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoAfCInRTqY

Boris Gelfand is also very jolly, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glHKPCYfxus

Vassily Ivanchuk also known for being jolly, if a little eccentric, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prsnlyfv4kQ, here he is dancing http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_R1lUsiFdg

Comment: Peter Svidler is always entertaining for me to listen to and he seems quick to give his rivals credit.

Answer (score 2):

Magnus Carlsen looks jolly to me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY27lgnPKWI